# Play partially downloaded mp4 video

Tags: ios, video, download, playback, partial

I am downloading an MP4 from a server by writing the file data directly to the app's documents folder. My question is - is there a way to start playing this file before it is fully downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://trac.mplayerhq.hu/ticket/748 this is not possible because important information is missing from the file. I haven't studied the container format myself to confirm that.